# FTP connection drivehq

Tags: java, android

I created an Android app which has an FTP connection, however when I start the app it says "unfortunately your app must stopped", and I can't find the problem.
I tried to enter local passive mode however it didn't help me, I also tried to run the app on my phone however it gave me the same message.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button scan;
    String contents;
    String format;
    TextView contentstext;
    TextView formattext;
    FTPClient  ftpclient;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //----------------------FTP-------------
        new FtpTask().execute();
        //ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        try {
        ftpclient.changeToParentDirectory();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




        scan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
        contentstext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.contentstext);
        formattext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.formattext);
        scan.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPClient> {
        protected FTPClient doInBackground(Void... args) {
            FTPClient  ftp = new FTPClient ();
            try {
                ftp.connect("ftp.drivehq.com");
                ftp.login("zule","****");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           return ftp;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(FTPClient result) {
            Log.v("FTPTask","FTP connection complete");
            ftpclient = result;
        }

    }
```

here is the logcat:

```
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.market/com.example.market.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.example.market.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-17 12:11:30.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What's there in line number 32, It is saying something is null there and you are trying to operate on null.

Comment: i dont know if there an internet connection on android emulator therefore i think it's null,however when i tested it on my android phone too,it also gave me the message:"unfortanelty your app must stop", there is another prblem that i dont know where

Comment: i tried with another server too, and i got the same message, i really dont know where is the problem with my code?maybe someone can give me an website that gives an ftp server for free which work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the stack trace. It says you have a NullPointerException on line 32.
If I counted right, that's this line:

```
ftpclient.changeToParentDirectory();
```

Notice that your class member `ftpClient` is not instantiated; so it's still `null` when you try to call `changeToParentDirectory()` on it.

Adding `ftpClient = new FtpClient( ... )` somewhere before this call should solve your problem. Add the correct parameters for the dots.

Comment: hi, there is a line there with " ftpclient = result;" so i dont think that ftpclient is null; also, i dont know if there an internet connection on android emulator therefore i think it's null,however when i tested it on my android phone too,it also gave me the message:"unfortanelty your app must stop",there is another problem that i dont know where

Comment: Looks like `FtpTask` is asynchronous; there is no guarantee that `ftpClient` will be assigned a value after the call to `new FtpTask()`; the call may not yet have finished when you reach `ftpClient.changeToParentDirectory()`. Something you may want to test to find out more.

Comment: i change it to "public void FtpTask()" without  asynchronous and it doesnt work for me too...anyone has any idea?myabe someone has an working server and working code that he can post here?i really dont know what to do?

Comment: The asynchronous part is because class FtpTask derives from `AsyncTask`. Find the line in your stack trace where you get the exception; if you still get a NullPointerException, find out which variable on that line is set to `null`.